# How to use VB library in C?

Tags: c++, c, vb.net

I am just starting to look at C/C++ for a project. I need to open a till drawer.

The till drawer I am using is Posiflex USB CR4500.

They provide a help guide for programmers to one the drawer. Having no experience with C/C++ I am a little bit stuck to say the least. This question may look a bit long, but the solution I'm sure will be pretty simple, so please read on.

I am using WxDev to code and now understand how to compile a script to an exe. The problem I am having is getting the actual code to work or even validate to compile. This is the instructions given by the supplier (which I am told are pretty basic).

> **Posiflex USB CashDrawer Series USB CR DLL v1.03 Programming Guide**
>
> The driver required to control the Posiflex USB Cash Drawer
>   is called "USBCR.DLL". When the Posiflex USB Cash Drawer Test
>   Program is installed, this driver is stored in folder
>   "C:\Windows\System" if the default Windows folder is
>   "C:\Windows". Please preserve this file "USBCR.DLL" in the
>   system folder for your software to control the Posiflex USB
>   Cash Drawer even if you want to uninstall the Posiflex test
>   program.
>
> The driver "USBCR.DLL" provides 7 function calls: 
>   The 1--5 functions are for USB CashDrawer series to use.
>   The 6--7 functions are for USB CashDrawer series to use.
>   The examples of Visual Basic are list below.
>
> **1.Public Declare Function OpenUSBcr LIB "usbcr.dll" () As Long**
>
> must be called before calling other functions
>
> return 0 on success
>
> **2.Public Declare Function CloseUSBcr Lib "usbcr.dll" () As Long**
>
> call this function before exiting your program
>
> return 0 on success
>
> **3.Public Declare Function DrawerOpen Lib "usbcr.dll" (ByVal ID As Long) As Long**
>
> return 0 on sending commands successfully, -1 on error
>
> 'ID' is the drawer number from 0 to 7
>
> 4.Public Declare Function DrawerState Lib "usbcr.dll" (ByVal ID As Long) As Long
>
> return the drawer status
>
> high nibble is the drawer ID, and
>
> low nibble is 0 if drawer is open, 1 if drawer is closed
>
> return -1 on error
>
> **5.Public Declare Function RetrieveStatistics Lib "usbcr.dll" (ByVal ID As Long, ByVal idx As Long, ByRef buf As Any, ByVal size As Long) As Long**
>
> return 0 on sending commands successfully, -1 on error
>
> 'size' is the number of bytes which can be held by 'buf'
>
> 'buf' will hold the value read from memory in cash drawer
>
> This function used to Retrieve the device statistics of Unified POS1.8.
>
> **6.Public Declare Function OpenUSB Lib "usbcr.dll" () As Long**
>
> must be called before calling other functions
>
> return 0 on success
>
> This function is for USB CashDrawer Series to use,
>
> and it can drive too.
>
> **7.Public Declare Function CloseUSB Lib "usbcr.dll" () As Long**
>
> call this function before exiting your program
>
> return 0 on success
>
> This function is for USB CashDrawer Series to use.
>
> and it can drive USB CashDrawer too.
>
> Note : For C++ programs: use __stdcall compiler option

So I need to know how to write these I presume in C due to the message at the bottom.

What have I tried so far?

This link http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/94473-calling-usbcrdll-to-open-a-cash-drawer/ gave me this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

$usbcr=DllOpen("usbcr.dll")
$call=DllCall($usbcr,"long","OpenUSBcr")
If @error Or $call[0]<>0 Then
  ConsoleWrite("Fail."&@CRLF)
Else
  ConsoleWrite("Success."&@CRLF)
Endif
}
```

However this is failing at the first hurdle. I also have form this link
http://msgboard.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/showthread.php?95962-calling-a-dll-in-order-to-open-a-cash-drawer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
declare usbcr OpenUSBcr L
declare usbcr DrawerOpen LL

aa = OpenUSBcr()
bb = DrawerOpen(7)   '7 is the drawer identifier
}
```

This is also failing, although I am sure it is my complete lack of experience with C.

Rather than pasting the other twenty or so links I am looking at, below is some code that does actually seem to work to a degree, although it prints statuses rather than opening the till. I have run this code on two machines, one with the till and one without. When printing `OpenUSBcr` on the machine without I get -2, on the one with the till I get 0, therefore it is getting the status correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "windows.h"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  HMODULE hm;
  long (*ou)();
  long (*cu)();
  long (*wp)(long);
  long (*ps)(long);

  SetLastError( 0);
  hm = LoadLibrary( "usbcr.dll");
  printf( " hm = %p, %lu \n",hm,GetLastError());
  if ( hm==NULL ) return 1;

  SetLastError( 0);
  ou = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"OpenUSBcr");
  printf( " ou = %p, %lu \n",ou,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  cu = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"CloseUSBcr");
  printf( " cu = %p, %lu \n",cu,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  wp = (long(*)(long)) GetProcAddress( hm,"DrawerOpen");
  printf( " wp = %p, %lu \n",wp,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  ps = (long(*)(long)) GetProcAddress( hm,"DrawerState");
  printf( " ps = %p, %lu \n",ps,GetLastError());

  printf( " OpenUSBcr = %ld \n", ou());
  for (long i=0;i<8;++i) // test 8 drawers
  {
    printf( " st1(%ld) = %ld \n", i,ps(i));
    printf( " ocr(%ld) = %ld \n", i,wp(i));
    printf( " st2(%ld) = %ld \n", i,ps(i));
  }
  printf( " CloseUSBcr = %ld \n", cu());

  FreeLibrary( hm);
  return 0;
}
```

Taken from https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=435296. The solution is probably right in front of my eyes, but any help anyone can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: `how to compile a script to an exe` OUCH MY EYES! In C/C++, there is no script, but source code, a script is executed within a interpreter, a source code is compiled in a executable.

Comment: You can't just stick VB code in a C++ program.

Comment: Also, are you doing C or C++, thoses are **different** languages, choosing one of them is the first step.

Comment: I presume I would need to use C, judging by the comment in the bottom of the programmers guide. Although I tagged as C++ also as the comment also suggest it can be achieved with C++ also. I understand these are two different languages, not sure on the specifics of why but I do understand.

Comment: [Difference between C and C++](http://studytipsandtricks.blogspot.fr/2012/05/15-most-important-differences-between-c.html) are multiples, the link just provide a few of them.

Comment: The last code work because it s the only one really written in C, first one seems to be VB, I don t know what is the second one. You should first try programming in C a bit before trying to do this.

Comment: @DrakaSAN many thanks for the link seems easy enough to read. Like I say I am very new to this. PHP is my main language so this is quite foreign to me. If I can just ask then, presumably I need to get a copy of visual basic and test the other codes.

Comment: It s a option, but you should learn C too, it don t hurt and is really useful in a lot of other languages.

Comment: And please change the title of the question. This question will not be useful to future readers because of its title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don t have the time and SO is not the place to ask ready-to-use code, but I can try to help.

The library you re trying to use is written in VB, that s why your first two codes are in VB. The last code load the library (`LoadLibrary`, seems to be a function of windows.h) to execute the API.

I don t know what the first two code do at all, so I ll try to analyze the last.

(`//` and `/* ... */` are comment in C).

I am making a lot of wild guesses based on what I know of C, if anyone can confirm or infirm them, I would greatly apreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h> //Standard library, include printf, 
#include <time.h> //Time library, don t know why it is included

#include "windows.h" //Wild guess: include LoadLibrary, SetLastError, GetLastError...

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[]) //Basic main declaration, with the addition of __cdecl, which clean the stack (don t know why it is useful)
{
  HMODULE hm; //Structure, probably included in windows.h
  long (*ou)(); //Declare a pointer to function (Wild guess)
  long (*cu)();
  long (*wp)(long);
  long (*ps)(long);

  SetLastError( 0); //Clean the error
  hm = LoadLibrary( "usbcr.dll"); //Load usbcr to use its function
  printf( " hm = %p, %lu \n",hm,GetLastError()); //Print error, if it is 0, all did gone well
  if ( hm==NULL ) return 1; //If the library failed to load, terminate the execution

  SetLastError( 0);
  ou = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"OpenUSBcr"); //Wild guess: assign OpenUSBcr to the pointer
  printf( " ou = %p, %lu \n",ou,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  cu = (long(*)()) GetProcAddress( hm,"CloseUSBcr");
  printf( " cu = %p, %lu \n",cu,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  wp = (long(*)(long)) GetProcAddress( hm,"DrawerOpen");
  printf( " wp = %p, %lu \n",wp,GetLastError());

  SetLastError( 0);
  ps = (long(*)(long)) GetProcAddress( hm,"DrawerState");
  printf( " ps = %p, %lu \n",ps,GetLastError());

/*Previous assignement give us this:
  -ou is OpenUSBcr
  -cu is CloseUSBcr
  -wp is DrawerOpen
  -ps is DrawerState
*/

  printf( " OpenUSBcr = %ld \n", ou()); //Open the device
  for (long i=0;i<8;++i) //For each drawer (assuming there is 8)
  {
    printf( " st1(%ld) = %ld \n", i,ps(i)); //Get and print the state
    printf( " ocr(%ld) = %ld \n", i,wp(i)); //Print if the drawer is open
    printf( " st2(%ld) = %ld \n", i,ps(i));
  }
  printf( " CloseUSBcr = %ld \n", cu());//Close the device

  FreeLibrary( hm); //Unload the library (memory management)
  return 0; //Terminate normally
}
```

Basically, this C program "import" the library in a usable C form, and use thoses to check the statu of eight drawer.

You could edit the for part to make your program, assuming you learn C a bit and your task is simple.

Comment: Genius, got it working. I had an issue with the for loop not working (mentioning c99 and that i was not declared), so I manually created the three lines and hardcoded i. The drawer popped open. So many thanks for your time, the code commenting has certainly cleared this up for me and I will be sure to find some C tutorials and get learning, I'm now just ripping bits out that I believe I don't need.

Comment: You re welcome, just remember to don t ask for code, but for a way to understand the problem, it s what make the downvote rain actually.

Comment: Understood, I always try to avoid a solve it for me approach, I think not mentioning the fact I removed the for loop and therefore till7 in this case did not open was my downfall. Different language, same rules, rookie mistake. Many thanks for your help with this.